# Python - printing first 1000 primes doesn't stop

Tags: python, for-loop, primes

There has been a problem in my latest code, that I do not know how to solve, at all. Basically, I am printing out the first 1000 primes - but my code prints out prime numbers well beyond the first 1000 primes limit. I have specified in my code to stop at 1000. Here is my code:

```
import itertools

counter = 1

while (counter <= 1000):
    for i in itertools.count(start=3, step=1):
        for a in range(2, i/2):
            if (i % a == 0):
                break
        else:
            print i
            counter += 1
```

I really do not know how to fix this. Can someone help?

**Solution**

I fixed this code by adding this piece of code inside the else block:

```
if (counter == 1000):
    sys.exit()
```

Comment: Your break statement only breaks the `for a in range(2, i/2)` loop, not the one above it. So the `for i in itertools.count(start=3, step=1)` loop keeps going.

Comment: @BradBeattie well that's by design, and that's correct. The problem is they needed a second `break` to get out of the larger loop.

Comment: `for a in range(2, math.sqrt(i)+1)` would be a bit more efficient, since if `i` has a prime factor, then there is a factor less than or equal to `sqrt(i)`.

Comment: thanks unutbu - will do that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your version was stuck in the internal loop.

```
import itertools

 counter = 1

 for i in itertools.count(start=3, step=1):
    if(counter<1000):
        for a in range(2, i/2):
            if (i % a == 0):
                break
        else:
            print i
            counter += 1
    else:
       break
```

Answer (score 2):

`Count` never stops producing number so essentially you are stuck inside the `for` loop.

A quick workaround would be:

```
import itertools

counter = 1

for i in itertools.count(start=3, step=1):
    for a in range(2, i/2):
        if (i % a == 0):
            break
    else:
        print i
        counter += 1
        if counter > 1000:
             break
```

Answer (score 2):

You've had a number of responses on why your answer doesn't work. Here's how I'd do it! I'd rather build a prime number generator and pull from that instead.

```
class PrimeNumberGen(object):
    def __init__(self,max_prime=None):
        if max_prime:
            self.numbers = range(2, max_prime+1)
        else:
            self.numbers = itertools.count(start=2, step=1)
    def __next__(self):
        for num in self.numbers:
            for divisor in range(2, int(num**0.5)+1):
                if num % divisor == 0:
                    break
            else:
                return num

primes = PrimeNumberGen()
for _ in range(1000):
    print(next(prime))
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to initialize your counter once outside all your loops, the way you have it written you are resetting it inside your while each time:

```
counter = 0
nums = itertools.count(start=3, step=1)

while counter <= 1000:
   i = next(nums)
   for a in range(2, i/2):
        if i % a == 0:
            break
   else:
       print(i)
       counter += 1
```

Answer (score 0):

Even with you your solution your code prints 999 prime numbers instead of 1000.(last number should be 7919 instead of 7907) https://primes.utm.edu/lists/small/1000.txt

only problem in your code is,

`counter = 0    #instead of counter = 1`